# How can I implement a "highlight mode" using Backbone.js?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have started looking into Backbone.js and I seem to be having trouble figuring out how to implement a *highlight mode* for incomplete events in a todo list.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PnSPH/).

Each todo item has a checkbox that maps to its models `completed` attribute.

I have a button called *Highlight Incomplete* which I wanted to add a class to each item's `li` of which its model's `completed` attribute is `false`. I wanted it to *toggle* this mode, so one click highlights them and the next click removed all highlighting.

I wrote a filter on the model's collection to return these incomplete items. I thought I could use this, but I got stuck trying to figure it out.

I didn't want to add another attribute called `highlighted` to the model as it can be inferred from its `completed` attribute and it would only exist for its visual representation.

It should also be *live*, so if you have *highlight mode* on and add some new elements, they should be highlighted.

How can I do this?

Comment: If you structure your CSS to match your html heirarchy, and have your model states constantly updated, you won't have to worry about syncing issues: http://jsfiddle.net/PnSPH/5/

Comment: @rkw Good thinking, you should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you structure your CSS to match your html heirarchy, and have your model states constantly updated, you won't have to worry about syncing issues: http://jsfiddle.net/PnSPH/5

This fiddle handles the check box state: http://jsfiddle.net/PnSPH/6/

An alternative would be to stick with just having `.render()`, but have the template handle the `class` and `checked` status

Answer (score 1):

Have your `ListView` maintain a list of the `ItemView`s it creates inside of `appendItem`.  Your ItemViews represent a `<LI>` in the DOM and, based on what I see in your stylesheets, is where you want to toggle the `highlighted` class.  Have your ItemViews expose a method like `highlightIfIncomplete` and call it from `ListView.getIncompleted`.

Here's updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PnSPH/2/

Comment: I thought about doing that. Is it trivial to get it to work *live* (see question edit)? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't need collection.getIncomplete...

http://jsfiddle.net/7nX4S/1/